# How to analyse success of trades by time of day, day of week, duration from the output of an MT5 Expert Advisor

Tags: programming, csv

I have the output of an MT5 EA in csv format.  I want to analyse the output to identify best time of day, day of week, duration, buy or sell, consecutive wins and losses.

Ideally I would like to use a Python module to do this or a spreadsheet.

Help please ! TIA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At a minimum, you should provide example data, to show what is available in your output and in what form.